# Is there Python function to extract cell history from smartsheet?

Tags: python, smartsheet-api-2.0

I have been trying to extract the cell history from the Activity Log but due to some restrictions it threw up an error saying **You do not have the permission to view the history**. I am now planning to extract the same cell history with the help of Python, just need a clarity on where do I need to do that coding. in "Smartsheet" or "Python" with the API access. Kindly share your thoughts.

Thanks in advance

I tried to extract the cell history from the Activity Log in the smartsheet but it threw up an error saying "**You have no persission to view the details**"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can get a cell history object. You have to go cell by cell. See the documentation on Cell objects' [list cell history method](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/cells#operation/cellHistory-get).

```
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN)
cell_history_object = module_client.Cells.get_cell_history(
        sheet_id=ssid, row_id=row_id, column_id=column_id, include_all=False
)
# As an example, if you want the last time the cell was modified:
last_modified = cell_history_object.data[0].modified_at
```

One thing to keep in mind--it's getting cell history is resource-intensive and the API weighs it more heavily than other types of requests.  The smartsheet API rate limit is 300 requests per second per API token and one get_cell_history() request counts as 10 requests. See documentation on [rate limiting](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#section/Work-at-Scale/Rate-Limiting).

Answer (score 0):

Smartsheet does provide any API that allows to programmatically interact with Smartsheet data, including cell history. But we can install some python libraries like 'requests ' for making HTTP requests to the Smartsheet API.